# How do I set these li elements under eachother?

Tags: html, css

How do I get test3 to stand under test2, and test2 to stand under test1? I've been busy for hours trying to figure out how to get a centered responsive ul/li

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ItsGiovanni/th2q7fw7/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    *display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove your `float: left;` from the `li`.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* display: inline; */
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Test1</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th2q7fw7/5/)**

Comment: Wow, okay haha. Thanks! That did the job

Answer (score 0):

If you need the float property then move display property from ul to li and add clear property to left.

```
ul {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    *display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: block;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```